# Shift element by 2 when there is a change in value in a column and then forward fill using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, forward

I have a pandas dataframe with date index and 100 columns of stock prices.

I want to each stock, when ever there is a price change, there to be a lag of 2 and then after forward fill.

Eg data of 2 columns (subset of my data):

```
         Stock A    Stock B
1/1/2000    100 50
1/2/2000    100 50
1/3/2000    100 50
1/4/2000    350 50
1/5/2000    350 50
1/6/2000    350 50
1/7/2000    350 25
1/8/2000    350 25
1/9/2000    500 25
1/10/2000   500 25
1/11/2000   500 25
1/12/2000   500 150
1/1/2001    250 150
1/2/2001    250 150
1/3/2001    250 150
1/4/2001    250 150
1/5/2001    250 150
1/6/2001    250 150
1/7/2001    250 150
1/8/2001    75  150
1/9/2001    75  150
1/10/2001   75  25
1/11/2001   75  25
1/12/2001   75  25
1/1/2002    75  25
```

Now the output I desire is this:

```
    Stock A Stock B
1/1/2000        
1/2/2000        
1/3/2000        
1/4/2000        
1/5/2000    100 
1/6/2000    100 
1/7/2000    100 
1/8/2000    100 50
1/9/2000    100 50
1/10/2000   350 50
1/11/2000   350 50
1/12/2000   350 50
1/1/2001    350 25
1/2/2001    500 25
1/3/2001    500 25
1/4/2001    500 25
1/5/2001    500 25
1/6/2001    500 25
1/7/2001    500 25
1/8/2001    500 25
1/9/2001    250 25
1/10/2001   250 25
1/11/2001   250 150
1/12/2001   250 150
1/1/2002    250 150
```

Example of stock A:

When stock A changed first time (100 to 350), then previous value (100) was assigned to 2 days ahead (1/5/200). Then when it changed again from 350 to 500, 350 was assigned to 2 days ahead (1/10/2000) etc.....then a forward fill takes place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.where(df.diff(-1).fillna(0).ne(0)).shift(2).ffill()

                A      B
2000-01-01    NaN    NaN
2000-02-01    NaN    NaN
2000-03-01    NaN    NaN
2000-04-01    NaN    NaN
2000-05-01  100.0    NaN
2000-06-01  100.0    NaN
2000-07-01  100.0    NaN
2000-08-01  100.0   50.0
2000-09-01  100.0   50.0
2000-10-01  350.0   50.0
2000-11-01  350.0   50.0
2000-12-01  350.0   50.0
2001-01-01  350.0   25.0
2001-02-01  500.0   25.0
2001-03-01  500.0   25.0
2001-04-01  500.0   25.0
2001-05-01  500.0   25.0
2001-06-01  500.0   25.0
2001-07-01  500.0   25.0
2001-08-01  500.0   25.0
2001-09-01  250.0   25.0
2001-10-01  250.0   25.0
2001-11-01  250.0  150.0
2001-12-01  250.0  150.0
2002-01-01  250.0  150.0
```